# select inputs won't align inside table

Tags: javascript, html

I want to align to inputs next to eachother, these  select inputs are inside a table row.  Instead they keep stacking on top of eachother, any idea why?(There is plenty of room inside the cell)

```
                    <div class="spantoolbar">
                        <div class="styled-select">
                            <select style=" font-size: 12px;">
                                <option>option 1</option>
                                <option>option 2</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="styled-select">
                            <select style="font-size: 12px;" >
                                <option>option 1</option>
                                <option>option 2</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Y u no break the table row into two, or add style="display:inline;"!

Comment: My guess is the surrounding `<div class="styled-select">` need to be `float: left` otherwise the first <div> pushes the next one below it since they're block elements.

Comment: pots the css style you are using to style your input tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `float:left;` in both classes.

Answer (score 0):

A div by default is of `display:block`, meaning subsequent items will be placed under it. As srijan says in the comment, you'll need to add `display:inline;` to the "styled-select" class in  your css or use `span` instead of `div`.